# Problem importing a file from another class in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No named module named 'account'` when importing a `class Account` from another file `account.py` in python into my main file `Lab10.py`. I have tried using various methods in importing the file but am still getting the same error.
It is important to note that both of my python files are in the same folder or directory and both my file and classname are correct.

Solutions that I have tried to solve the error:

1. import `sys sys.path.append("/Users/MyNamePc")`
2. import `account account1 = account.Account('John Green', Decimal('50.00'))`
3. from `account import Account`

**Error Message and Traceback**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-383774029c8d> in <module>
      3 from decimal import Decimal
      4 import sys
----> 5 from account import Account
      6 
      7 # Create an Account Object with a Constructor Expression

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'
```

**Code:**

```
#account.py
from decimal import Decimal
class Account:
    """Account class for maintaining a bank account balance"""
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        if balance < Decimal('0.00'):
            raise ValueError('Initial balance must be >= to 0.00')
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposit money to the account"""
        if amount < Decimal('0.00'):
            raise ValueError('amount must be positive.')
        self.balance += amount
```

```
#Lab10.py - My main program
from decimal import Decimal
from account import Account
# Create an Account Object with a Constructor Expression
account1 = Account('John Green', Decimal('50.00'))
    
# Getting an Account’s Name and Balance
account1.name
account1.balance
# Depositing Money into an Account
account1.deposit(Decimal('25.53'))
account1.balance
# Account Methods Perform Validation
account1.deposit(Decimal('-123.45'))
# Attempting to modify the name and balance
account1.name = 'Bob Blue'
account1.balance = Decimal('12345.67')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code to a [mre]. If you are sure the class/module names are correct then we *don't* need to know what the class actually does and how it is used. What we *do* need to know is the *full* error, including the precise message and traceback, as well as the information to actually reproduce the setup – that's *how* you run the code, as well as *what* environment there is such as where the files are and the initial ``sys.path``.

Comment: where is `account.py` located relative to `Lab10.py`?

Comment: For the record, the code as shown works fine; the only thing missing is a ``from decimal import Decimal`` in ``account.py``.

Comment: @buran Like I said, account.py and lab10.py is in the same folder or directory

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have included from decimal import Decimal in account.py yet it is still giving me the same error "ModuleNotFoundError"

Comment: Please, check that you did not midspelled the file name.

Comment: @Respawn Which ``ModuleNotFoundError`` *exactly*? Again, please provide the entire error message and traceback.

Comment: @buran I did not mispell the name. My class and filename are correct

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My apologies. The Error I got is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'. Keep in mind that my filename is correct, my class name is correct. And both my files account.py and lab10.py are in the same folder

Comment: Thanks for adding the message. Now please just add the traceback and how you actually run the code as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-383774029c8d> in <module>
      3 from decimal import Decimal
      4 import sys
----> 5 from account import Account
      6 
      7 # Create an Account Object with a Constructor Expression

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I use Jupyter notebook and pycharm  IDE to run this code. As for the traceback and error, I have edited my question to include that

Comment: Just be sure that the name of the account.py is as you are importing. It seems your imported python file's name is not adjust the name of the python file. The code works correctly for me

Comment: @Ali_sh is the name of the python file I am importing is account.py. While the class name  in account.py is Account with a capital 'A'. I am trying to import it to my main file Lab10.py

Comment: The solution is well mentioned in the comments. But, since you still have issue, I [attached two files](https://gofile.io/d/Iq69Yy) to check them; They will show `ValueError: amount must be positive.` which is reasonable as it is coded in *account.py*.

Comment: @Ali_Sh I tried running your code and It did not work on my JupyterLab and Notebook. It still gave me the same error. However, it worked on my pycharm IDE. Please what IDE are you using?

Comment: @Respawn PyCharm.